# How do I add value to all integers of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, math

I have a string and I'm trying to add a value to all numbers within that string. 
the string looks like this: "AXE15!io68"

How do I make it look like: "AXF26!io79"

I am new to Javascript and would love if you guys could help make this code. thank you

Comment: Hi! It is not clear what would you expect for a string containing "9"? Should the result be "0", "10" or anything else? Please, add more details to the question. It is also better to try to code it by yourself and post the solution (which may not work correctly) you would came up with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\d+` match all the numbers and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) them with the incremented number. Here `match` will be a string. So, you need to convert it to number using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) before incrementing

```js
const str = "AXE15!io68";

const output = str.replace(/\d+/g, match => +match + 11);

console.log(output)
```